# How to add documentation after packages have already been installed?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have installed a bunch of packages to the snapshot database. I would now like a local copy of their documentation (even better if it's with [hyperlinked source](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3ecest/haddock2161_released_with_source_code/)). Is there a way I can tell `stack` to run `haddock` on all of them?

EDIT (copied from my answer):

It seems that the obvious `stack haddock package` will install haddock for the package, so

```
$ cd ~/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-3.0/7.10.2/doc
$ stack haddock *
```

seems to do what I want, with two downsides:

1. I'll still need to remember to pass the `--haddock` flag to every `build` (there isn't a `~/.stack/config` file, is there?)
2. It seems to rebuild them; is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: You might try the [standalone-haddock](https://github.com/feuerbach/standalone-haddock) app.

Comment: It doesn't look like what I want; I'm fine with the relative links, and it doesn't seem to offer anything else beyond straight-up `haddock`?

Comment: I think it just shells out to your `haddock` executable. If it doesn't invoke it with the correct options, try creating a wrapper script to add the options you need.

Comment: I don't know what options to pass `haddock`. I'm relying on `stack` (and in the past, `cabal`) to invoke it.

Comment: See my answer for details on how to create a wrapper script which always adds `--hyperlinked-source` to the haddock command line. If you create the wrapper the `stack haddock` command will probably create the hyperlinked source.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the obvious `stack haddock package` will install haddock for the package, so

```
$ cd ~/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-3.0/7.10.2/doc
$ stack haddock *
```

seems to do what I want, with two downsides:

1. I'll still need to remember to pass the `--haddock` flag to every `build` (there isn't a `~/.stack/config` file, is there?)
2. It seems to rebuild them; is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Considering that it answered my question, I felt like it was worth posting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Download and build the newest haddock. The build instructions are
in `README.md`.

```
git clone https://github.com/haskell/haddock.git
cd haddock

cabal sandbox init
cabal sandbox add-source haddock-library
cabal sandbox add-source haddock-api
cabal install --dependencies-only
cabal build
```

Then install the new haddock as `haddock.real`

```
cp dist/build/haddock/haddock /some/bin/dir/haddock.real
```

Step 2. Create a wrapper script named `haddock`:

```
#!/bin/sh

/some/bin/dir/haddock.real --hyperlinked-source "$@"
```

Don't forget to make it executable and put it in your path.

Step 3. Download and build `standalone-haddock`:

```
mkdir build-standalone-haddock
git clone https://github.com/feuerbach/standalone-haddock.git
cd standalone-haddock
cabal build
cp dist/build/standalone-haddock/standalone-haddock /some/bin/dir/
```

An example of how to use `standalone-haddock`:

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
cabal get heredoc-0.2.0.0
standalone-haddock -o doc heredoc-0.2.0.0
```

Then open `doc/heredoc/index.html` in your browser.

When you navigate to a type definition you should see a `Source` link on the right and that will bring you to the new hyperlinked source.

Comment: This barely addresses the question at all. For example, one problem with this approach (I tried something similar) is that `stack` doesn't use the `haddock` that's on the `PATH`; another is that I want docs for packages already installed.