# How do I install Haddock from gitHub?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, cabal-install, haddock

Okay, so in "[Why isn't Cabal hyperlinking my sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236857/why-isnt-cabal-hyperlinking-my-sources)", I found out that I needed haddock 2.16.2 to use `cabal install --haddock-hyperlink-source`. So, I installed it from gitHub by cloning it, and running `cabal install -j` in the repo, and it said

```
(Other stuff)
Configuring haddock-2.16.2...
Building haddock-2.16.2...
Installed haddock-2.16.2
```

It doesn't seem like it is installed though. First of all, `cabal install --haddock-hyperlink-source` still doesn't hyper link my documents. Also `ghc-pkg haddock` doesn't see haddock at all. If I run `haddock --version`, it still says 2.16.1. Same thing for `~/.cabal/bin/haddock --version`. When I do `cabal install haddock`, it doesn't warn about a reinstall, but does notice that something is up with `haddock-api`.

How do I install the gitHub version of `Haddock`?

Comment: You installed it, it's probably just further down your path than the haddock you got from haskell platform or wherever you got haskell from

Comment: @Cubic Do you know how I can get cabal to use it instead?

Comment: Just put it in your PATH.

Comment: @user5402 I'm not even sure where I installed it to.

Comment: Reinstall it and carefully read the output. Also try using the -v flag with cabal to get more verbose output.

Comment: Also look in the `dist` directory (might be in a subdirectory)

Comment: Finally - here are my instructions for building the latest haddock: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32171973/866915